# Is there a way to save the...?

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

Just wondering if there is any way for

> The older brother to avoid dying ?

Comment: This is not like the Walking Dead, where you get to make choices. This is just a linear story.

Comment: Thought there might have been something I missed that could alter the outcome.

Comment: Upvote for no spoiler :)

Comment: I believe it's based on a book or story so no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. In the end, things can only turn out one way.

Comment: If you're curious, though, that moment (and what comes after) is central to the game's entire design; so naturally, there's no way to avoid it! [This interview](http://www.giantbomb.com/articles/a-tale-of-one-game/1100-4736/) with the game's creative director may be of interest.